# Set Theory - Given 2 sets, are they order-isomorphic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

We are given the sets $A=(1,2]\cup ((3,4)\cap \mathbb Q)$ and $B=(1,2)\cup ((3,4)\cap \mathbb Q)$ with the standard order $\leq$ of the reals.

Are they order-isomorphic? Meaning, is there a bijective function $f:A\to B$ such that $a_1 \leq a_2 \in A$ implies $f(a_1) \leq f(a_2) \in B$?

Answer: There isn't.

The reason for this (this is what the teacher said) is that the set $A^{*} = \{x\in A| |\{a\in A| a \geq x\}|\leq \aleph_0\}$ has a minimal value with the standard order. While $B^{*}=\{x\in B| |\{b\in B| b \geq x\}|\leq \aleph_0\}$ does not.

Firstly, I don't understand at all why this is true. And second, even if it is true, why does that imply that there isn't an order perserving isomorphism between $A$ and $B$? I don't see the relation between the 2 statements.

Comment: Can you define ℵ0 ?

Comment: $\aleph_0$ is the cardinal of the natural numbers. It is the smallest of the infinite cardinals, and is the cardinal number of all infinite countable sets.

Comment: Hint: can you prove that the minimal value of $A^*$ is 2 ?

Comment: Yes, I agree it is.

Comment: and that it is not for B ?

Comment: for $B^{*}$ there is no minimal value. but why does that have any implication on the original $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Try to do a contraposition and suppose there exist such a f. What would happen to A* and its minimal value when you apply f ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between A and B is what happens with '2'. There is a hint, which is to prove that there is no order isomorphism, so we try to find something that is true in A and not true for B and that concerns orders.

Little digression as an example of what your teacher is trying to do : is there an homeomorphism between an infinite line and an infinite plane ? Answer : no. Because if you remove a point from a line you have 2 different connex sets, whereas this does not hold with a plane.

Here the teacher tries to find such a property (with sets that are countable/not countable) that should hold in both A and B if there was such an order isomorphism

Comment: I see...so if $A$ and $B$ are order-isomorphic, then there $A^{*}$ and $B^{*}$ must have similar properties

Comment: Exactly, and it is a simple exercise to prove that $B^*=f(A^*)$

Comment: @Oria: For some added information about *why* that property was considered, it's worth noting that $A \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $B \cap \mathbb{Q}$ *are* order isomorphic. So whatever property you use to solve the given problem has to have some way of distinguishing between intervals of rationals and intervals of reals.